# Модуль Random. Всегда в том же месте

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
class Apple:
    def __init__(self):
        self.weight = 25
        self.lenght = 25
        self.random1 = 0
        self.random2 = 0
    def drawApple(self, win):
        pygame.draw.rect(win, pygame.Color('Green'), pygame.Rect(self.random1, self.random2, 25, 25))
    def randomAplle(self):
        self.random1 = random.randint(-500, 500)
        self.random2 = random.randint(-500, 500)
    while control.flag:
         win.fill((0, 0, 0))
         control.control()
         snake.draw(win)
         apple.drawApple(win)
         snake.move(control)
         pygame.display.update()
```

У меня яблоко всегда появляется в одном месте (0, 0)

Comment: А вы где-то вызываете randomAplle?

Comment: в этом и была проблема, спс